# Object Factory registration of template class hierarchy

Tags: c++11, templates, design-patterns, factory

I implemented a general object factory following the guidelines of Andrei Alexandrescu's book *Modern C++ Design*, so I can define a class hierarchy like this (I will write the code in the most simplified way, avoiding implementation details or memory allocation/deallocation issues; I'm aware of these things and I would like to focus the discussion on the main issue):

```
// File "base.h"
#include <string>
#include "singleton.h"
#include "object_factory.h"
class Base;

using SingletonBaseFactory = Singleton
<
     ObjectFactory
     <
         Base,         // Abstract product type
         std::string,  // Identifier type
         Base* (*)()   // Concrete product creator type
     >
>;

class Base {
    // Define the interface (virtual functions, virtual dtor)
public:
    // Wrap the Factory method
    static Base* Factory(const std::string& ID) {
        return SingletonBaseFactory::Instance().Factory(ID);
    }
};

// File "derived_1.h"
#include "base.h"
class Derived_1 : public Base { /* ... */ };

// File "derived_2.h"
#include "base.h"
class Derived_2 : public Base { /* ... */ };
```

and register each derived class within an anonymous namespace in the corresponding implementation file:

```
// File "derived_1.cpp"
#include "derived_1.h"
namespace {
    Base* CreateDerived_1() {
        return new Derived_1;
    }

    const bool registered = SingletonBaseFactory::Instance().Register("Derived_1", CreateDerived_1);
}

// Same for Derived_2 in file "derived_2.cpp"
```

Therefore, an user that wants to use this hierarchy in his code has just to invoke the `Base::Factory` method with a proper identifier:

```
// File main.cpp
#include"base.h"
int main(){
    Base* pb = Base::Factory("Derived_1");

    // Do stuff with pb

    return 0;
}
```

Now, suppose I have a template class hierarchy, say:

```
// File "baset.h"
#include <string>
#include "singleton.h"
#include "object_factory.h"

template<class T>
class BaseT;

template<class T>
using SingletonBaseTFactory = Singleton
<
    ObjectFactory
    <
        BaseT<T>,         // Abstract product type
        std::string,      // Identifier type
        BaseT<T>* (*)()   // Concrete product creator type
    >
>;

template<class T>
class BaseT {
    /*Define the interface*/ 
public:
    BaseT Factory(const std::string& ID) {
        return SingletonBaseTFactory<T>::Instance().Factory(ID);
    }
};

// File "derivedt_1.h"
#include "baset.h"
template<class T>
class DerivedT_1 : public BaseT<T> { /* ... */ };
```

In this case the registration is an user responsibility for each type T he wants to use, before using the class hierarchy:

```
// File main.cpp
#include "baset.h"
#include "derivedt_1.h"

bool register_derived_1_int = SingletonBaseTFactory<int>::Instance().Register("Derived_1", [](){ return new DerivedT_1<int>; });

int main() {
    BaseT<int>* pb = BaseT<int>::Factory("Derived_1");
    return 0;
}
```

Keeping in mind that the ID of each derived template class is the same for every type `T`, would it make sense to delegate the registration responsibility to the developer of each derived class (rather than the user) even in the templated case?
If so, is there a workaround to achieve it?

**EDIT:**

I found this work https://www.artima.com/cppsource/subscription_problem.html which addresses the object factory registration problem in the templated case. 
However, the registration of the derived classes is still a responsibility of whoever knows the type(s) the derived class can be instantiated with.
Typically, the class developer does not have such a knowledge - the user does have it. 
So, again, is there any method to dismiss the user from the responsibility of registering the derived class?